# Penny dropped in the water: What would you see if transmitted light is parallel to the incident surface

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

[image]

I'm working on a problem which asks what is the greatest diameter of a paper you can use to totally shield a penny dropped in the water from view.

[image]

The question claims that if the transmitted light was made totally parallel to the surface, then you will not see it. (full solution [here](https://em.groups.et.byu.net/embook/ch8/s8.23.pdf))

I have trouble visualizing this. Can someone provide me reason as to why you will not see the penny if the transmitted light was parallel to the surface of the water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that the refracted ray is at the **critical angle**. I tried it myself with 1 INR coin.

[image]

Although the image I took was not from a ray $90^o$ from the normal, it was $1^o-2^o$ lesser. The meniscus of water interfered with my observations.

When we look at the coin from the normal, a flat 2d image appears. As the angle between the normal and the refracted ray approaches 90, the 2d image will start converging to a 1d line segment. The image will be reduced to a thin silver line segment.

Answer (score 1):

because in order for you to see, the light must reah your eyes. If the transmitted light was made totally parallel to the surface, then it will never reach your eyes. Thus, you will not see it.

Comment: What would you see if you place your eyes right at the surface?

Comment: I cannot imagine what you will see because our eye surface is 2d, so some part will be either outside of inside the water. the part over the water will not see anything, the part on the surface will see a flat image (a copper coored segment) and the part below will see the penny.